# Selenium IDE - StoreElementPresent - Element Not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

**Hey guys**, 
I'm running a script using **SELENIUM-IDE** for Mozilla Firefox for web automation.
In the script, I'm searching the **"next"** button on the webpage and would like to know if it's available or not. If so, Click on it and go to the next page, if not restart the script.
When going on a page without the next button I get an error and a

> "Test Case Failed"

**Commands I Use:**

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=a._3a693.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow</td>
    <td>bool</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>'${bool}' </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>'${bool}' == false</td>
    <td>STARTSCRIPT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=a._3a693.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**In the Log results I get:**

```
[info] Executing: | storeElementPresent | css=a._3a693.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow | bool |
[info] Executing: | echo : 'true'
[info] Executing: | gotoIf | '${bool}' == false | STARTSCRIPT |
[info] Executing: | clickAndWait | css=a._3a693.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow |  |
[error] Element css=a._3a693.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow not found
[info] Test case failed
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

It is getting same css selector.Go to browser and inspect "next" button and copy xpath of this element to uniquely identify your element.

Comment: should i use it for storing? `xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '......')])[2]` this is the unique path for the specific page, how can i make it generic to use for every page?

Comment: The contain feature has an ability to find the element with partial text.
so if the attribute value changes dynamically, selenium will find the element and test case wont be failed.

Comment: ill give it a shot.. should i use the full xpath adress anyway?

Comment: when i use storeElementPresent for  `<td>storeElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '')])[2]</td>
 <td>bool</td>` bool returns true even on a page without the next button than the clickAndWait fails..

Comment: trying this now  `<td>storeElementPresent</td>
 <td>//a[contains(text(),'Next')]</td>
 <td>bool</td>` 
hopefully this will work